# How can I import formulas and references from other files. (cross reference)

Tags: cross-referencing, citing

I am writing a response letter to resubmit a manuscript for IEEE journals.

My manuscript file has a filename 'main.tex', and is written as follows:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{...}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\begin{document}

\title{...}

\author{...}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
...
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}
...
\section{...}
...
\section{...}
...
\section{...}
...

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,main}

\end{document}
```

Then, my response letter is written as follows

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
...
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

---

In this case, I want to refer to the equations and citations used in my manuscript, 'main.tex', in the response letter.

What is the best way to do this?
Indeed, at present, I am referring to the formulas as (3), (10), (44), etc., the sections as I, II, II-A, etc., and the literature as [1], [4], [11]-[14], etc., by hand.
Please recommend some correct and efficient way to refer to the Eqs., Sections., Algs., Refs. used in the original manuscript.
Now, whenever the numbering is changed in the original manuscript, I am changing all numbers in the response letter by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To import citation:

```
\usepackage{xcite}
```

To import cross references:

```
\usepackage{xr}% or xr-hyper if you use hyperref
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, `xcite` works well, but `xr` does not work well. However, I finally solved it by using `\usepackage{zref-xr}`, `\zxrsetup{tozreflabel=false, toltxlabel=true, verbose}`, and `\zexternaldocument*{main}`, instead of `xr`.